# Sphinx unlimited tocdepth

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar, read-the-docs, tableofcontents, toctree

I am stuck on the depth of the toctree of my sidebar doc. Here's my doc : https://aff3ct.readthedocs.io/en/user_doc_dev/simulation/parameters/cdc/cdc_bch/cdc.html

As you can see, on the sidebar the toctree does not go deeper than the fourth level, but I have two other levels under. There is at the top of the page the `Edit on GitHub` link then you can see the source code.

I tried `:maxdepth: -1` in any **toctree** directive but it changes only the display of the page's TOC and not of the sidebar's.

I tried on the first line of my first top file `:tocdepth: 6`, or with -1 or any big number, but it changes nothing.

I tried sphinxcontrib-fulltoc, but it never compiled; I did't find why.

Any idea ? Is it really possible to display deeper on the sidebar ? Is it a known bug ?

Comment: The Read the Docs theme has a configuration option called navigation_depth (https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/…). Does it work if you change the value to 6 or -1?

Comment: Thank you mzjn, how could I miss that ?! I was looking for "toc depth" or "side bar depth" but not "navigation depth". Works perfectly as expected  ! Thank you again.